# Bash command to get list of files in directory

Tags: bash, shell

What do I have to type to get a list of files in the current directory satisfying the following conditions?

- Hidden files (starting with ".") should NOT be included
- Folder names should not be included
- The filenames should include their extension
- Filenames with spaces should not be broken up into multiple list items

(I intend to loop over the results in a foor loop in bash script.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using * and then skipping over the directories as the first step in your loop?

```
for F in * ; do
    if test -d "$F" ; then continue ; fi
    echo "$F"
done
```

Comment: You need a statement terminator (semicolon or newline) before `done`.

Comment: @tripleee there is a newline there.

Comment: The formatted post showed it for me.  I don't disbelieve you - perhaps there is a browser specific, user specific, etc. bug.

Comment: See the source and/or formatting help to spot the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Using just bash:

```
files=()
for f in *; do [[ -d $f ]] || files+=("$f"); done
printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Upvoting and big congratulations for the 100K rep!

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type f
```

should work fine for your needs

`maxdepth 1` -> Searches only in current dir

`! -name '.*'` -> Searches files NOT matching name pattern '.*'

`type f` -> Searches only files, not dirs

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 find $folderPath  -type f  -printf "%f\n" | grep -v '^[.].*'
```

you only have to change the $folderPath.

**Explanation**

> find $folderPath  -type f  -printf "%f\n"

With find command you can search into the folder with a several options.

- '-type f' search only the files, if you want filter by folder, you only have to change the 'f' for 'd'
- '-print "%f\n"' format the output of the command. '%f' extract the filename and '\n' add a return.
- '|' is a pipe. With  the pipe you can use the output of a command to use it like a input var in other command.

> grep -v '^[.].*'

- grep is a command to looking for a regex expresion into a input text.
- with the option '-v '^[.].*', you exclude the values that contains the regex. In this case, the words that start with a . (dot).

To close the explanation, if you use another '|' (pipe) you can process every result of the command like the input for another. This has a better performance, because the output is in a Stream, and need less memory to process the result.

Comment: What would you use in a for loop in bash script? Is it reasonable to use find in there, or is there a way that performs better?